# Frontend testing - Mocking server response - json generator vs static responses

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, frontend

I have a server that does some complicated business logic actions upon HTTP requests. I want to write unit tests and functional tests for the frontend using that server. After reading online a lot, I saw there are many ways to achieve this, the 2 I think may best suite our case are:

1. Save static responses - For every scenario I want to test, record the server response, save the response in a file in the repository and use it in tests.
2. Create a json response generator, one that I can easily create content on the fly for tests.

The pros and cons I see in each:
For static files:

**Pros:** Given a right setup for recording backend responses - should be fairly easy to implement new tests.

**Cons:** If the API changes, there is no good way for me to map all the files that use that API and know to update the tests. The result of this is it's hard even to know what is the scope of change required to support such a change.

For JSON generator:

**Pros:** Easy to change the API response is it is in one place.

**Cons:** The ramp up for this is much more complicated, and it will take time until the it will be easy to add tests quickly.

Of course there are more pros and cons for each, but these are the ones that in my view contradict the most between the 2.

My question are these:

1. Are there more options we neglected? (I don't want unit tests to go over the network to mock servers)
2. Which of the 2 do you recommend and why?
3. What are the best practices for this?

Thanks ahead,

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this would fall into the category of integration tests. Your  tests (ideally) shouldn't be making external network calls - frontend or backend - so mocking the data is the way to go. I'll share my thoughts on your two options:

**Static responses** - This is the most straightforward method, not much can go wrong as long as the real server responses don't differ too much. Syncing the static responses with the "real" API becomes the crucial factor here. It would require you to communicate closely with the team working on the API itself, or, as you said, devise a method of detecting relevant changes.

**Response Generator** - I believe that this is the more robust approach since any change to the API will be reflected in the generated responses. It also pertains to the integration aspect of the tests, since if the responses are generated by the same code that runs the API, you can be sure that any new changes are included.

I would recommend generating the responses via the backend code and incorporating integration tests into your build steps. That being said, if you're on a frontend team working against an API that is constantly changing without the teams knowledge, perhaps you need to look into your communication methodologies so that both teams can be synced up and surprise changes can be minimized.

Comment: We have integrations tests as well, that is covered. The API doesn't change so much and when it does it is communicated - but once communicated you want to do the changes in the front and be confident we covered all cases.